# wrapping text disappearing after giving overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jss

to fix the wrapping issue of this text ---> testing the be Bhere I am here I am here I am here I am here I
                am testing the be Bhere I am here I am here I am here I am here
                I am 12 34 56 78 90 123 456 7778 88889 9999 999690909090

- I used `overflow: "hidden"` in the class right_box.
- wrapping text got fixed.
- but when i decrease the screen size I am seeing some of the texts are getting hidden.
- I googled and found line height will fix it,
- so I gave it in the two classes  sportsCardHeaderItemHeadingValue and right_box
- but still its not fixing.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-e89n0

```or-tag-here
sportsCardHeaderItemHeadingValue: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#263238",

    wordWrap: "break-word",
    lineHeight: 1.2
  },

 right_box: {
    border: "1px solid #000",
    // padding: 5,
    // background: '#ff0',
    marginTop: 8,
    marginRight: 8,
    float: "left",
    //  width: 150,
    height: 55,
    overflow: "hidden",
    lineHeight: 1.2
  },

<div className={classes.right_box}>
              0<div className={classes.sportsCardHeaderItemHeading}>Sports</div>
              <div className={classes.sportsCardHeaderItemHeadingValue}>
                testing the be Bhere I am here I am here I am here I am here I
                am testing the be Bhere I am here I am here I am here I am here
                I am 12 34 56 78 90 123 456 7778 88889 9999 999690909090
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen with a set height and overflow hidden?  Can you rephrase your question, it isn't clear what you are asking to be fixed. What is your expected result?

Comment: @DrewReese hey when I decrease the screen size I dont see this text 12 34 56 78 90 123 456 7778 88889 9999 999690909090 https://e89n0.codesandbox.io/

Comment: If the containing element can't grow, i.e. it has a height of 55px, and you've constrained the width, it will overflow out of the element. You added the rule `overflow: hidden;` which hides this overflow. What result are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the height of `right_box` to grow to fit content? Do you want the height to remain 55px and display a horizontal scroller? Something else?

Comment: @Drew hey I wanted  the height of right_box to grow to fit content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a height set on `right_box` so it can't grow height-wise to fit content.  Also, when resizing the view to then restrict the width, it then overflows the content. When you add the CSS rule `overflow:hidden;` to `right_box` it then hides the overflow and you can't see it.

I commented out the height and overflow rules (approx lines 424-425) and now you can see the element expands to fill width and the height grows to fit content.

```
right_box: {
  border: '1px solid #000',
  // padding: 5,
  // background: '#ff0',
  marginTop: 8,
  marginRight: 8,
  float: 'left',
  //  width: 150,
  // height: 55, // don't restrict height
  // overflow: "hidden", // element can grow now so don't need to hide overflow
  lineHeight: 1.2,
},
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-c8g56?fontsize=14)